# How to parse this nested dictionary datastructure in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary (named `dict1`) that has the following structure:

```
dict1 = {
    'Classroom': [{
        'Subject': "Calculus",
        'Students': [
            {'Name': "Joe", 'Age': 12, 'Weight': 126, 'Gender': "Male"},
            {'Name': "Doug", 'Age': 13, 'Weight': 95, 'Gender': "Male"},
            {'Name': ..., 'Age': ..., 'Weight': ..., 'Gender': ...}
        ]
    }]
}
```

The list (which contains name, age, weight, and gender) within this dictionary is very long, and I wanted to parse the **Name**, **Age**, and **Gender** out, and append them onto another list like this:

```
mylist = [("Joe", 12, "Male"), ("Doug", 13, "Male"), ... ]
```

I tried seraching online and tinkered around with code such as this:

```
mylist = []
dict2 = dict1['Classroom'][0]['Students'][0]['Name']
mylist.append(dict2)
```

But what happens is that it only appends the first name (Joe). Furthermore, I'm not sure how to parse three items (name, age, and gender) at the same time. Does anyone have a way to do this without having to use libraries?

Comment: Where is the original dict file?

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ Apologies, I updated it. The original dict is the first dictionary that I wrote on my post.

Comment: The dictionary 'dict' consists of just one parent key and the value is a list.

Comment: @Ṁữŀlɪgắnậcễơưṩᛗ Correct, but there are dictionaries within that list, which is why I tried doing the "dict['classoom'][0]" thing to specify what items in the lists I want. But it only prints one name for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dict1` contains one key, `'Classroom'` whose value is a `list` with one entry.
That entry, is also a `dict` which contains two keys. You want the `'Students'` key as that contains the list of all the students. It is a list. Iterate through that list and group the fields into a tuple.

It is technically a list `['Students']` nested within a dictionary `['Classroom'][0]` within a list `['Classroom']` within a dictionary `dict`.

The code will be

```
mylist = []
studentlist = dict1['Classroom'][0]['Students']
for s in studentlist:
    m = (s['Name'], s['Age'], s['Gender'])
    mylist.append(m)
```

For the test case

```
classroom = {'Classroom': 
    [{'Subject': "Calculus", 'Students': 
        [
        {'Name': "Joe", 'Age': 12, 'Weight': 126, 'Gender': "Male"}, 
        {'Name': "Doug", 'Age': 13, 'Weight': 95, 'Gender': "Male"},
        {'Name': "Omg", 'Age': 50, 'Weight': 99, 'Gender': "Female"}
        ]
    }]
}
```

you will end up with

`[('Joe', 12, 'Male'), ('Doug', 13, 'Male'), ('Omg', 50, 'Female')]`

Comment: This works, thanks! I was also just now thinking of using "for s in studentlist", so good to know that I'm learning! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
student_list = []
classroom_list =  dict1['Classroom']
# this is the first iteration list
for classroom in classroom_list:
    student_list = classroom['Students']
    # this is the second iteration list
    for student in student_list:
        student_list.append(student['Name'], student['Age'], student['Gender'])

#student_list = [("Joe", 12, "Male"), ("Doug", 13, "Male"), ... ]
```